# Boxing of user-defined value types

Tags: c#, .net, il, value-type

According to MSDN, if a struct were defined, that struct should override all methods inherited from the object class. That is recommended to avoid the unnecessary boxing when calling any inherited method such as ToString.

According to the MSDN, to determine if and when boxing occurs, an IL instruction "box" can be found in the MSIL code.

I wrote the following test to see the boxing.

```
using System;

namespace TestingBoxing
{
    public struct StructX
    {
        public int member1;
        public int member2;
    }

    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            StructX s1;

            s1.member1 = 2;
            s1.member2 = 5;

            string str = s1.ToString();

            Console.WriteLine(str);
        }
    }
}
```

However, the boxing instruction cannot be seen in the MSIL code below although ToString is called without being overridden in the struct definition.

```
.method public hidebysig static void  Main(string[] args) cil managed
{
  .entrypoint
  // Code size       37 (0x25)
  .maxstack  2
  .locals init ([0] valuetype TestingBoxing.StructX s1,
           [1] string str)
  IL_0000:  ldloca.s   s1
  IL_0002:  ldc.i4.2
  IL_0003:  stfld      int32 TestingBoxing.StructX::member1
  IL_0008:  ldloca.s   s1
  IL_000a:  ldc.i4.5
  IL_000b:  stfld      int32 TestingBoxing.StructX::member2
  IL_0010:  ldloca.s   s1
  IL_0012:  constrained. TestingBoxing.StructX
  IL_0018:  callvirt   instance string [mscorlib]System.Object::ToString()
  IL_001d:  stloc.1
  IL_001e:  ldloc.1
  IL_001f:  call       void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
  IL_0024:  ret
} // end of method Program::Main
```

How that could be explained ?

Reference article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973858.aspx#code-snippet-6

Comment: Perhaps it is implicit in the `constrained` call. See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.constrained%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: .constrained seems to have no effect in this context, i tried to override the ToString method, but the .constrained was generated.

Comment: constrained will always be generated if i understand correctly, just what it does will change

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be explained by looking at what `Constrained` does.

A field is typically `constrained` in order to use `callvirt` in a standard way without needing to explicitly box. It does the following:

> If thisType is a reference type (as opposed to a value type) then ptr is dereferenced and passed as the 'this' pointer to the callvirt of method.
>
> If thisType is a value type and thisType implements method then ptr is passed unmodified as the 'this' pointer to a call  method instruction, for the implementation of method by thisType.
>
> If thisType is a value type and thisType does not implement method then ptr is dereferenced, boxed, and passed as the 'this' pointer to the callvirt  method instruction.

What this means is (as stated by the MSDN article):

> This last case can occur only when method was defined on Object, ValueType, or Enum and not overridden by thisType. In this case, the boxing causes a copy of the original object to be made. **However, because none of the methods of Object, ValueType, and Enum modify the state of the object, this fact cannot be detected.**

Emphasis mine. Basically saying that if boxing does occur, it cannot be determined via IL.

Constrained MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.constrained%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion it is the callvirt instruction that does the boxing. Looking at the disassembly for your code we get this disassembly on the line where ToString is called

```
00DB287A  mov         ecx,26933C0h  
00DB287F  call        00AD2100  
00DB2884  mov         dword ptr [ebp-18h],eax  
00DB2887  mov         edi,dword ptr [ebp-18h]  
00DB288A  add         edi,4  
00DB288D  lea         esi,[ebp-10h]  
00DB2890  movq        xmm0,mmword ptr [esi]  
00DB2894  movq        mmword ptr [edi],xmm0  
00DB2898  mov         ecx,dword ptr [ebp-18h]  
00DB289B  mov         eax,dword ptr [ecx]  
00DB289D  mov         eax,dword ptr [eax+28h]  
00DB28A0  call        dword ptr [eax]  
00DB28A2  mov         dword ptr [ebp-1Ch],eax  
00DB28A5  mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp-1Ch]  
00DB28A8  mov         dword ptr [ebp-14h],eax
```

And if we change the code to:

```
public struct StructX
{
    public int member1;
    public int member2;

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return member1.ToString() + " " + member2.ToString();
    }
}
```

We get:

```
02352875  lea         ecx,[ebp-8]  
02352878  call        dword ptr ds:[4DD33E0h]  
0235287E  mov         dword ptr [ebp-10h],eax  
02352881  mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp-10h]  
02352884  mov         dword ptr [ebp-0Ch],eax
```

Now my assembly is quite rusty but it seems to me that all this moving around is actually boxing. When the type is a value type The C# compiler can skip call virtual since it is certain that the method cannot be overridden in a derived type.

Edit: As pointed by other answers the callvirt is still there it is the CLR that does the optimization.